# Angular - build DOM element in a loop and apply to DOM at once

Tags: angular

We have a list with thousands of child items. Lets say something like:

```
<div>
   <div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i;">
     {{i}} - {{item.title}}
   </div>
<div>
```

Since there are many of them, the loop takes some time.

I am wondering, how does angular do this? Does it apply each `div` to the DOM with each iteration or does it build the whole list and then applies them at once?

If it doesn't do it at once, is there a way to accomplish that?

Is there something like vanilla javascript `DocumentFragment`?

Or should the parent be hidden (`ngIf` with boolean that gets set to `true` once all children are build) until loop is done?

Answer (score 1):

Just go through the source code of [`ngFor`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a2087a1978dfd96a1d426b6814510f642f717fb9/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L136) line 245. It watches for changes through the hook `ngDoCheck`, then iterates through the changes identified by [`IterableDiffers`](https://angular.io/api/core/IterableDiffers) one by one using [`forEachOperation`](https://angular.io/api/core/IterableChanges) and applies them to the view.

If you have lot of rows, then you need to do optimization of rendering, you can implement.

1. [Virtual Scrolling](https://v11.material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview)
2. [Pagination](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-can-create-pagination-angular-shibaji-debnath/)

To optimize your UI, you cannot render multiple rows since there is a limit to how many the browser can handle, you can use the above two methods to stay within the limit with good performance!

Comment: thanks for the reference to the code! couldn't I build `documentFragment`, apply all elements to it and then apply it to template at once?

Comment: i cannot use paging/virtual scrolling

Comment: @tlzg angular does not have support for that I think

Answer (score 1):

You should consider **pagination** as a mandatory topic in component rendering.

But if you only require to show a list of "index - title", why do you use several divs?

Use a simple pre with a pre-calculated value in .ts:

```
get myList() {
    return this.items.map((item, i) => `${i} - ${item.title}`).join('\n');
}


<div>
    <pre>{{myList}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. of course, pagination is a standard way of keeping the number of elements at reasonable number but in this instance i cannot use it. /code is just an example)